# What is a correct definition of 3NF (3rd / Third Normal Form)? - problems with definition - R(A,B,C,D,E,F)

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

I have a problem with 3rd normal form. I find in the internet different contrary definitions and right now I don't know whether this relation with given functional dependencies is in 3rd normal form or not.

R(A,B,C,D,E,F)

A → BC
C → DA
E → ABC
F → CD
CD → BEF

What is a correct definition of 3NF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normal forms - 2nd vs 3rd - is the difference just composite keys? non trivial dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474203/normal-forms-2nd-vs-3rd-is-the-difference-just-composite-keys-non-trivial-d)

Comment: What reference(s) were you told to use? What definitions will be ok with your instructors? The duplicate has 2 definitions of 3NF & 2 of 2NF if you decide to use the 3NF definition that uses 2NF. Many academic textbooks and slides (also videos) are free online.